# Создать счетчик через замыкание

Tags: javascript, generate, замыкания

Есть такое задание:

> Напиши функцию создания генератора `sequence(start, step)`. Она при вызове возвращает другую функцию-генератор, которая при каждом вызове дает число на 1 больше, и так до бесконечности. Начальное число, с которого начинать отсчет, и шаг, задается при создании генератора. Шаг можно не указывать, тогда он будет равен одному. Начальное значение по умолчанию равно 0. Генераторов можно создать сколько угодно.

Даны тесты для проверки:

```
var generator = sequence(10, 3);

console.log(generator()); // 10
console.log(generator()); // 13
```

Я создал обычный генератор:

```
function sequence() {
    let callNumber = 0;
    return function () {
        return ++callNumber;
    }
}
```

Comment: функция есть, осталось ей параметры добавить, тебе даже написали какие

Comment: в тот то и дело,что не получается ничего(

Comment: так а что ты пробовал-то?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Половина дела сделана:

```
function sequence() {
    let callNumber = 0;
    return function () {
        return ++callNumber;
    }
}
```

Теперь согласно заданию нужно добавить два параметра

```
function sequence(start=0, step=1) {
    let callNumber = 0;
    return function () {
        return ++callNumber;
    }
}
```

для *step*, [значение по умолчанию](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) `1`, для *start* = `0`

Осталось только их использовать:

```js
function sequence(start = 0, step = 1) {
  let callNumber = start;
  return function() {
    var returnValue = callNumber; // значение для вывода
    callNumber += step; // готовимся к следующему шагу
    return returnValue;
  }
}

var generator = sequence(10, 3);

console.log(generator()); // 10
console.log(generator()); // 13

var generator2 = sequence();

console.log(generator2()); // 0
console.log(generator2()); // 1
```

---

Вариант с [настоящим генератором](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*):

```js
function sequence(start = 0, step = 1) {
  function* gen(start, step) {
    while (true) { // бесконечно генерируем значения
      yield start; // выдаем значение 
      start += step; // готовимся к следующему шагу
    }
  }
  var generator = gen(start, step); // создаем генератор с нужными параметрами

  return function() {
    return generator.next().value; // получаем значение из генератора
  }
}

var generator = sequence(10, 3);

console.log(generator()); // 10
console.log(generator()); // 13

var generator2 = sequence();

console.log(generator2()); // 0
console.log(generator2()); // 1
```

Answer (score 4):

Моё решение:

```js
function sequence(start, step) {
    start = start || 0;
    step = step || 1;
    start -= step;
    return function() {
        return start += step;
    }
}


var generator = sequence(2, 3);
console.log(generator());
console.log(generator());
console.log(generator());
```

Comment: Невероятно! Вы это сделали? Теперь у меня еще больше вопросов. Спасибо огромное! Весьма благодарен!

Comment: не за что ) сам проходил эти задачи :)

Answer (score 3):

Замыкания нету, зато есть собственно [генератор](https://learn.javascript.ru/generator))

```js
function* sequence(start = 0, step = 1) {
    start -= step;
    while(true){
        yield start += step;
    }
}

var generator = sequence(2, 3);
console.log(generator.next().value);
console.log(generator.next().value);
console.log(generator.next().value);
```

Comment: Первый раз вижу такую конструкцию. Как мне найти информацию о данном коде?

Comment: @АлексейДодока добавил в ответ ссылку

Comment: Такая функция указанные тесты не пройдет :)